# Looking for new ideas for exercises

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique

[Sworkit](https://sworkit.com/exercises) is pretty good for demonstrating and explaining various exercises, but I'm looking for something more. Like difficult and weird exercises, you know, something with an unfamiliar range of motion. I mean, I make up my own exercises here and there, but I'm looking for something that's fun, unheard of, undervalued, and esoteric. What do you know that is like this? This includes the novel use of equipment, like, say using a disconnect [grip triangle](https://www.roguefitness.com/rogue-grip-triangle-standard-grip) for some difficult balancing push ups or using a barbell as an ab roller.

Comment: Google the word "calisthenics". That will keep you busy for the next 8 to 10 years :)

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to train for skill acquisition, like in gymnastics. There are endless skills to get, so there's plenty of variety, it's very fun IMO

- L-Sit / V-Sit
- tuck planche / straddle planche / full planche
- handstand / handstand pushups
- handstand walk / handstand pirouettes
- iron cross (there are progressions for this but it's quite advanced)
- back bridge
- L-pullups / L-muscle-ups
- rings muscle ups
- Hollow Holds (with ankle weights if you want it harder)
- Arch holds
- back flip / front flip
- pommel horse circles
- etc etc

These should keep you busy quite a while. Some of these do require spécial equipment that you'll only find in a gymnasium, but most of if can be done without

Comment: This is good. I also am looking for alternate ways of, or combining, equipment for (safe) unique exercises. Like, the other day I saw a video of a guy using a barbell as an ab roller.

Comment: Most of these are done on the gymnastic rings. I recommend everybody to get a pair of these since they are really cheap, allow you to do a huge range of exercises, and provide a great instability that will work your stabilizers like not much else

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you try some brazilian jiu jitsu, which is a mixture of grappling/wrestling/submissions/judo. Do a drop in class. You'll be using muscles you never knew existed (a lot of hip motion and weight distribution mechanics). A lot of great condition rolling (6 minute sparring sessions) with an opponent where the fear of claustrophobia and getting choked out has you going hard.

It's basically 3d chess with a human whose body opens up a plethora of moves that you will have to drill and train in to either counter/beat. It's going to suck in the beginning but if you're looking for a workout and a challenge, you'll be hooked (no pun intended).

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbhFdjiPe6w) video?

Comment: Yeah, I think tai chi is great for movement/meditation purposes but not for the average joe looking for self defense martial arts in a short time span.

Comment: Agreed. Just thought to show you. ^_^